# Exception deserialize JSON to an object with special charters

Tags: c#, asp.net, json, json-deserialization

I am using the code below to deserialize JSON to an object, it is almost working like it should, but if the JSON is containing some special charters, it throws an error. How can I make the code so it can handle special charters?
If I use UFT-8 encoding, it isn't throwing any errors, but then the special charters is not right.

```
 public static T ConvertJsonToObject<T>(string json)
    {
        DataContractJsonSerializer js = new DataContractJsonSerializer(typeof(T));
        MemoryStream ms = new MemoryStream(System.Text.Encoding.GetEncoding("iso-8859-1").GetBytes(json));

        T response = (T)js.ReadObject(ms);
        ms.Close();
        return response;
    }
```

Thanks very much in advance.

Comment: Could you post some json that does not get deserialized?

Comment: Strings in .NET are not encoded. However, you can encode strings to a sequence of bytes using encodings like UTF-8 and ISO-8859-1. In your question I do not see a sequence of bytes (a stream or byte array) as input to your function. Anyway, `DataContractJsonSerializer` only supports `Encoding.UTF8`, `Encoding.Unicode` and `Encoding.BigEndianUnicode` so trying to force the serializer to read from an ISO-8859-1 encoded string will not work. Is your problem that the the input string contains invalid characters? Then you have to look upstream for bugs related to encoding.

Comment: Here are the JSON that is causing the problem: {\"ID\":1,\"City\":\"København\"}

Comment: @Martin Liversage: This is returning the byte[]: System.Text.Encoding.GetEncoding("iso-8859-1").GetBytes(json));

Comment: @PNR: Simply replace `Encoding.GetEncoding("iso-8859-1")` with `Encoding.UTF8` in your code. As I said before `DataContractJsonSerializer` only works with a few encodings including UTF8. If you are using UTF8 there will be no problems handling `København` or other Danish letters like `æ` and `å`.

Answer (score 0):

Thanks very much for your replies!

I found a soloution using Newtonsoft.Json (JsonConvert.DeserializeObject(json))